# .SelectSingleNode in Powershell script using xPath not working on extracting values from web.config file

Tags: powershell, xpath, web-config, selectsinglenode

Okay, so here is the snippet of my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<connectionStrings>
...
</connectionStrings>
</location>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<appSettings>
<!--IT Ops-->
<add key="SomeOtherKey" value="SomeOtherValue" />
<add key="SiteDomain" value="somedomain.com" />
<add key="SomeOtherKey" value="SomeOtherValue" />
....
</appSettings>
</location>
</configuration>
```

What I'm trying to do is find the  node using xPath via Powershell. A couple things to note about this XML file:

there are multiple:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

values in the xml file. They surround other nodes like  etc...

I can find and replace the connection string values successfully using this script

```
$WebConfigFile = Join-Path $destination Web.config
[xml]$WebConfigXml = Get-Content ($WebConfigFile)
$WebConfigXml.configuration.location[2].connectionStrings.add | % { $_.connectionString = $_.connectionString -replace "some value", $sqlServerName }
```

But when I go to replace the add key="SiteDomain" value using this script:

```
$node = $WebConfigXml.configuration.location[3].appSettings.SelectSingleNode("add[@key = 'SiteDomain']")
$node.value = "someValue"
$WebConfigXml.Save($WebConfigFile)
```

it does not work. The $node value in this case contains an empty string.

I'm also trying just to read the node like this:

```
$appSettingsSection = $WebConfigXml.configuration.location[3].appSettings;
$existingSiteDomain = $appSettingsSection.SelectSingleNode("add[@key='SiteDomain']")
```

And I'm still getting an empty string for the $existingSiteDomain value.

I've looked at samples using SelectSingleNode and I can't quite seem to figure it out. Not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your XML file has a namespace:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

so you need a namespace manager for [`SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx) (see section "Remarks"):

> XPath expressions can include namespaces. Namespace resolution is supported using the **XmlNamespaceManager**. If the XPath expression includes a prefix, the prefix and namespace URI pair must be added to the **XmlNamespaceManager**.

Something like this should work:

```
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($WebConfigXml.NameTable)
$ns.AddNamespace("ns", $WebConfigXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
$node = $WebConfigXml.SelectSingleNode("//ns:add[@key='SiteDomain']", $ns)
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but now I'm getting an error from Powershell. It doesn't know XmlNamespaceManager is: "XmlNamespaceManager : The term 'XmlNamespaceManager' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.". I ran "$psversiontable.psversion" on the powershell command line and it says I have Powershell version 3.0 installed. Is this some type of versioning problem?

Comment: Okay, I amend my previous comment. It is now working. I think there was some other syntax issue in my script that was causing this error. The code you provided worked! Thanks so much. I'm new to Powershell and xPath, so I had no idea about this namespace issue.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative can be by using [Select-Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet:

```
$nameSpace = @{ x=$WebConfigXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI }    
$result = Select-Xml -Xml $WebConfigXml -XPath "//ns:add[@key='SiteDomain']" -Namespace $nameSpace
```