# Change XML Element value with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

I'm only finding stuff on how to change the attribute values of a XML element here on StackOverflow.

But how do we change the value of the element itself using PowerShell?

I currently have:

**XML**

```
<Task>
  <Settings>
  ...
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>blablabla</Command>
      <Arguments>CHANGETHISVALUE</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$filePathToTask = C:\Task.xml
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($filePathToTask)
$element =  $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Arguments")
$element.InnerText("newtext")
$xml.Save($filePathToTask)
```

However, I can't seem to use methods on the last variable. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

- Added code

The error that I'm getting is *You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression*

I think my problem lies at:

```
$ElementToChange =  $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Arguments")
```

Which stays null, but I have tried methods like `.SelectNodes` and playing around with the `//Arguments`tag but still no success

Comment: If you want us to tell you what you're doing wrong, you need to tell us what yo *do.* And what error that produces.

Comment: I'm sorry @AnsgarWiechers , I thought my mistake was maybe obvious by only the code (like usual when I post something) but you're right, I will edit it now

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`InnerText` is a property, not a method. It's used like this:

```bsh
$element.InnerText = "newtext"
```

Also, I suspect that your original data (unlike the XML sample you posted) uses namespaces. AFAICS that's the only possible reason why `$xml.SelectSingleNode('//Arguments')` would return an empty result.
 XML files exported from the Windows Task Scheduler definitely are namespaced:

```xml
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task‌​">
  <!-- ... -->
</Task>
```

Namespaces are not like other node attributes and affect not only the node itself, but also its child nodes. For selecting nodes from an XML with namespaces you need a [namespace manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881581/1630171):

```
$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
$element = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//ns:Arguments', $nsm)
```

Answer (score 10):

When I run:

```
$filePathToTask = "C:\temp\Task.xml"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($filePathToTask)
$element =  $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Arguments")
$element.InnerText = "New Text"
$xml.Save($filePathToTask)
```

And re-check the output, I do see the updated value:

```
<Task>
  <Settings>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>blablabla</Command>
      <Arguments>New Text</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I enclosed the path in quotes, otherwise I was getting an error on the load line. That's good practice anyway, since the parameter for the Load method takes *string filepath* as input.
Then as Ansgar mentions, use the assignment operator ("=") to set the new value in memory, then dump to file.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean with "dump to file" ? You just mean save it or?

Comment: Yes, I mean "Write to disk"