# Set x XML node to value in Powershell

Tags: powershell, repeat, xmlnode

I have this PowerShell script in which values for an XML-file will be set by the script. This works perfectly fine when all child nodes are uniquely named. However, I'm adapting the XML-file to one where some nodes are repeated. Now I get an error in Powershell.

My question is, how to set the X'th node in XML to a certain value via PowerShell?

In short, my script works like the following:

```
cls

[xml] $xml1 = '<Lvl1>
                    <Lvl2>""</Lvl2>
                    <Lvl2>""</Lvl2>
                </Lvl1>' 

$xml1.Lvl1.Lvl2='./'

$xml1.Save("text.xml")
```

There is two times the same node (Lvl2), that's why I get the following error in PowerShell: "Cannot set "Lvl2" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties."

When I remove one (Lvl2) node, the script works like a charm.

Please advice.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699869/change-xml-element-value-with-powershell

Comment: @luuk, I don't see an answer to my question in the link you send me. I am able to change node property. However, when there is more then one node with the same name, I am stuk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use .NET syntax, it works like a charm.

```
$xml1.SelectSingleNode('Lvl1/Lvl2[2]').InnerText='./'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml1 = [xml]@'
    <Lvl1>
        <Lvl2>""</Lvl2>
        <Lvl2>""</Lvl2>
    </Lvl1>
'@

$xml1.GetElementsByTagName('Lvl2') | ForEach-Object { $_.InnerText = './' }

$xml1.Save("text.xml")

Get-Content -Path "text.xml" # debugging output
```

**Debugging output**: `.\SO\60280990.ps1`

> ```
> <Lvl1>
>   <Lvl2>./</Lvl2>
>   <Lvl2>./</Lvl2>
> </Lvl1>
> ```

Above approach works even for a bit more complicated input data e.g. as follows:

```
$xml1 = [xml]@'
<root>
    <Lvl1>
        <Lvl2>"a"</Lvl2>
        <Lvl2>"b"</Lvl2>
    </Lvl1>
    <Lvl0>
        <Lvl1>
            <Lvl2>"c"</Lvl2>
            <Lvl2>"d"</Lvl2>
        </Lvl1>
    </Lvl0>
</root>
'@
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the child nodes of `Lvl1` as aray and then use the index to adjust the wanted node:

```
[xml] $xml1 = '<Lvl1>
                    <Lvl2>""</Lvl2>
                    <Lvl2>""</Lvl2>
                </Lvl1>' 

$lvl2Nodes = @($xml1.Lvl1.ChildNodes)

$lvl2Nodes[1].'#text' = "blah"  # updating the second childnode only

$xml1.Save("D:\text.xml")
```

Result:

> ```
> <Lvl1>
>   <Lvl2>""</Lvl2>
>   <Lvl2>blah</Lvl2>
> </Lvl1>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
PS D:\TEMP> type lvl.xml
<Lvl1>
                    <Lvl2>"test1"</Lvl2>
                    <Lvl2>"test2"</Lvl2>
                </Lvl1>
PS D:\TEMP> $xml = New-Object XML
PS D:\TEMP> $xml.Load("lvl.xml")
PS D:\TEMP> $element =  $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Lvl1/Lvl2[2]")
PS D:\TEMP> $element.InnerText ="bla"
PS D:\TEMP> $xml.Save("lvl2.xml")
PS D:\TEMP> type lvl2.xml
<Lvl1>
  <Lvl2>"test1"</Lvl2>
  <Lvl2>bla</Lvl2>
</Lvl1>
PS D:\TEMP>
```

In the XmlPath (i.e. '/Lvl1/Lvl2[2]') the '[2]' refers to the second time this thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

[Paweł Dyl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60281461/45375) provides a concise solution that *bypasses* [PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375), which uses the familiar *dot notation*, in favor of using .NET methods directly.

However, **PowerShell's dot notation is both convenient and uses familiar syntax, so it's worth sticking with it, where possible and appropriate**.

Unfortunately, **in the case at hand that is only possible with a *hybrid* approach**, combining dot notation (using the element or attribute names as directly as *property* names) with native properties of the underlying [`System.Xml.XmlNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode)-based types:

Note: I'm using the following modified XML and variable name `$xml` in the commands below:

```
[xml] $xml = @'
<Lvl1>
  <Lvl2>a</Lvl2>
  <Lvl2>b</Lvl2>
  <Other><Stuff>c</Stuff></Other>
</Lvl1>
'@
```

**To assign a value to the *first* `Lvl2` child**, you can use the following approach:

```
# Assign to the *first* Lvl2 element.
$xml.Lvl1['Lvl2'].InnerText = './'
```

- Using the *indexer* (`['Lvl2']`) instead of *dot notation* (`.Lvl2`) utilizes the [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) type's *type-native indexer* to target the *first* child element by the given *name*.
- That element's `.InnerText` property can then be assigned to.

**If you need to assign to a child element *with a given index***, a different approach is needed, using the numeric (`0`-based) indexing of an `XmlElement`'s `.ChildNodes` collection (a streamlined version of [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60281554/45375)):

```
# Assign to the *last* Lvl2 element.
$xml1.Lvl1.ChildNodes[-1].InnerText = 'last'
```

---

**What *doesn't* work** as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0:

Unfortunately, **indexing directly into the child elements using dot notation alone does *not* work for *assignments***:

```
# DOESN'T WORK: PowerShell *quietly ignores* the assignment.
$xml.Lvl1.Lvl2[-1] = 'last'
```

This surprising behavior has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11922).

However, ***getting* a value this way (typically) works fine**:

```
# OK
PS $xml.Lvl1.Lvl2[0]
a
```

**Caveat**:

**If a named element happens to be the *only* child element *and* it itself has element *children*, indexing does *not* work**, preventing the unified treatment of scalars and collections that PowerShell normally provides:

```
# DOES NOT WORK, because there is only a single 'Other' element
# *and* it has a child element.
PS $xml.Lvl1.Other[0]
 # !! No output
```

Surprisingly, PowerShell uses the type-native *by name* indexer to look for an element *named* `'0'` - which by definition fails, given that XML element names mustn't start with *digits*.

[This GitHub suggestion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11923) proposes use of PowerShell's automatic positional indexing in this case, based on the argument being an *integer*.