# Call inner text of an element in a multiNode XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Clients xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <set>
        <name>mario1</name>
        <sn>GSI100-A-00100</sn>
        <status>OK</status>
        <version>V</version>
    </set>
    <set>
        <name>mario2</name>
        <sn>GSI100-A-00101</sn>
        <status>OFF</status>
        <version>v49</version>
    </set>
    <set>
        <name>mario3</name>
        <sn>GSI100-A-00101</sn>
        <status>OK</status>
        <version>v49</version>
    </set>
</Clients>
```

and am trying to locate a node with `<name>` equal to the value of a variable (in this case `$find`) and trying to return the innertext of the `<status>` element of the same node. This is what I do, but all I get is null.

```bsh
$xmledit = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument

$xmledit = "C:\Users\bigadmin\Desktop\Projects\AutoUpdate\test.xml"

[xml]$Xmlnew = Get-Content ($xmledit) -Encoding UTF8

$find = "mario1"

foreach ($search in $Xmlnew.clients.set) {
    $nodeexists = $search.SelectSingleNode("name") |
                  Where {$_.nodeexists -eq "$find"}

    return $nodeexists.clients.set.sn.InnerText
}
```

Comment: To just get the `Status` replace the whole foreach with `$xmlnew.clients.set | Where-Object Name -eq $find | Select-Object Status` or short without a header `($xmlnew.clients.set | Where-Object Name -eq $find).Status`

Comment: `SelectSingleNode("//set[name[text()='$find']/status")`? But since your XML data is namespaced you also need a [namespace manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881581/1630171).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ty got the logic.